# Full Text search returns duplicate keys

Tags: sql-server-2005, full-text-search

I have a search like the example below. The problem is that the result returns a key muliple times if the term "beach" is in myTextColumn multiple times, for example "I went to the beach because the beach is cool". I need it to be returned only once.

```
  SELECT DISTINCT          
    Src.[Key] AS MyID
FROM            
    CONTAINSTABLE(MyTable, myTextColumn, N'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL,beach )',500) Src
ORDER BY 
    MyID
```

Comment: Which db is this?

Comment: The database server is Microsoft SQL 2005

Comment: This is the answer but I'm not allowed to answer my own question.
It turns out that the problem was cause by a bad full text search index. It had to be rebuild with do not track changes, and the correct word breaker for the given language.

Comment: I believe you can answer your own question. You just cannot mark it as an answer for two days. Try it, if not, we can always ping the moderators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was cause by a bad full text search index. It had to be rebuild with do not track changes, and the correct word breaker for the given language.